# Extract evince's bookmarks from a pdf and add them to another

Tags: evince, file-metadata

Using evince I bookmarked a pdf file (in ubuntu 16.04). I want to copy these evince's bookmarks. I found they are stored as metadata and can see them using

> gvfs-info myfile.pdf

But I found no way to "paste" these bookmarks to the file metadata, if I copy it to another location or another computer. Found the same [problem here](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?295720-Any-way-to-save-and-see-Evince-s-bookmarks) with a suggestion (cp --preserve=all) that does not work.

(I mostly use ubuntu 16.04 with cinnamon but I also have some installations with versions of Mint.)

Comment: This might be useful : https://askubuntu.com/questions/294285/where-are-evince-bookmarks-stored

Answer (score 2):

The answer you linked to was wrong - not even remotely close to correct.  The attributes preserved by `cp` are ONLY filesystem attributes (ownership, timestamps, permissions).  file metadata is completely unrelated.

There isn't any easy way to copy application-specific data like `evince`'s bookmarks to another system.  The bookmarks aren't stored IN or with the file, they're stored by evince using [GIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIO_(software)).

You could extract the metadata with `gio info`, store it in a file, and then restore it on the remote system.  For example, if using `scp` to copy the file on the remote host:

```bash
gio info -a "metadata::evince::bookmarks" filename.pdf  | 
  sed -n '/metadata::/ s/^.*: //p' > filename.bookmarks

scp filename.pdf filename.bookmarks user@remote:/path/to/store/file/
```

Then, on the remote system:

```bash
cd /path/to/store/file/
gio set filename.pdf 'metadata::evince::bookmarks' "$(cat filename.bookmarks)"
```

---

BTW, variations of this method can probably also be used to restore GIO metadata to files if you've used standard unix tools (like `cp` or `mv`) to copy or move the files around, rather than staying within GIO-aware applications like `nautilus`

Comment: Note: as is usual for Gnome software, the documentation is abysmal - at best it's barely adequate as reference material, but there are no explanations or examples of anything.  You have to figure this stuff out by trial-and-error, and even if you get something that works, it still feels like voodoo, or like fragile guesswork that will break when they decide to come up with a shiny new registry clone.  Writing scripts like this wouldn't be necessary if their file browser `nautilus` had readily accessible options to export GIO data related to a file **AND** to import such data from a file.

Comment: the problem arise in multiple situations such as mailing the pdf (ex. to me), pdf read from different OS'es in the same computer (using multiple boots or on a shared folder for vitual box etc.). gio is not in ubuntu repositories so I cannot verify the solution

Comment: try `gvfs-info` and `gvfs-set-attribute`.  they're the old versions of the commands, now subsumed into `gio` (on my debian sid boxes, they still exist as sh wrappers calling `gio info` and `gio set` - after first displaying a message like "This tool has been deprecated, use 'gio info' instead.")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot cas. Used: 
`gvfs-info -a metadata::evince::bookmarks: myold.pdf`

then:

`gvfs-set-attribute -t string mycopied.pdf metadata::evince::bookmarks "extracteddataenclosedindoublequotes"`